# Binding silverlight combox in entity framework c#

Tags: silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am new in silverlight and i want to
bind data from Entity Data source in combox
like WindosForm
for exmple

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "CategoryID";
        comboBox1.DataSource = NorthwindEntities.Categories;            

    }
```

Thank you all.

Comment: and what is your problem exactly?

Comment: how i load data in combox in Silverlight??

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
 comboBox1.ItemSource= NorthwindEntities.Categories;
```

and you need to post XAML for more help.